# How can I filter an array which contains a child array property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have this Object (called "checklist")
[image]

inside the property "items", I have an array with 197 items. Like that:
[image]

The checklist is a useState:

```js
const [checklist, setChecklist] = useState(undefined);
```

I'm trying to filter like that, to "update" my checklist:

```js
let newChecklist = {};
  if (project?.analysisData?.actionPlan == "no") {
    newChecklist = checklist?.items.filter(
      (item) => item.conformityStatus !== "initial_status"
    );
    setChecklist(newChecklist)
  }
```

But it's not working. Shows this error:

[image]

Remembering, I don't want to filter only the items. I want all the object, but without the items that have this condition that I said.

Thank you so much!

Comment: `checklist.items = checklist.items.filter(...)` ?

Answer (score 3):

As described by Barmar:
You can use the filter method to add the condition:
if property *conformityStatus* as the "initial_status" and then filter it out.

Ejm:

```js
const checklist = {
    items: [
        {
            conformityStatus: "initial_status",
            title: "Hi 1"
        },
        {
            conformityStatus: "initial_status",
            title: "Hi 2"
        },
        {conformityStatus: "other"},
        {
            conformityStatus: "initial_status",
            title: "Hi 3"
        },
        {conformityStatus: "other"},
        {
            conformityStatus: "initial_status",
            title: "Hi 4"
        },
    ]
}

const filter_items = checklist.items.filter(item => item.conformityStatus === "initial_status")

console.log(filter_items)
```

Comment: Isn't it the way around? 
`.filter(item => item.conformityStatus !== "initial_status")`

Comment: Perfect, it worked. But I noticed that I have a problem. This checklist is a useState.

const [checklist, setChecklist] = useState(undefined); 

How could I do this filter to the checklist? Without create a new checklist

Comment: Absolutely Sr. @Bickelmeister, I just noticed after publishing it. My bad :) 
Regarding your next question Caio I'll recommend you review the useState hook to set the New value. If you don't what a duplicate object, after filtering it, you can replace the current ChecList with the filter value.
(Examples of use)https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usestate.asp